# Entity Framework Inheritance InverseProperty

Tags: entity-framework

When i link two entities to one with the same herited navigation property i can't generate my db..
I saw i can duplicate the property "House" and specify the InverseProperty on each of herited types but i wan't centralize the property.
*(naturally i have more of code associated at the property)*

```
public abstract class DbEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Houses")]
public class House : DbEntity
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("House")]
    public virtual ICollection<Garden> Gardens { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("House")]
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}


public abstract class HousePart : DbEntity
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HouseId")]
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}
[Table("Gardens")]
public class Garden : HousePart {}
[Table("Rooms")]
public class Room : HousePart {}
```

> House: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'House' is not valid. Type 'Room' of FromRole 'House_Rooms_Target' in AssociationType 'House_Rooms' must exactly match with the type 'Garden' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

Thanks if you have a good way to centralize the implementation of property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's work like that :

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Garden>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.House)
        .WithMany(d => d.Gardens)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.HouseId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
          .HasRequired(c => c.House)
          .WithMany(d => d.Rooms)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.HouseId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```